# Создание функции для отображения Window

Tags: c#, wpf

Хочу сделать функцию для того чтобы постоянно не писать:

```
AddServiceWindow addServiceWindow = new AddServiceWindow();
this.Hide();
addServiceWindow.Show();
```

Пытаюсь реализовать функцию ShowWindow, но Rider ругается на this.

```
void ShowWindow(Window showWindow)
{
    showWindow.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Подскажите как можно реализовать данную задумку?

Comment: передать this в ShowWindow

Comment: а не подскажете как это реализуется в C#?

Comment: Если ShowWindow находится в классе, то this там уже существует и его передавать не надо. Разместите функцию в классе окна, которое надо скрывать

Comment: Я вам советую очень хорошо над этим всем подумать, ведь окно это не просто вывод, окно это еще и данные, которые вместе с этим окном идут, точнее связь с данными. Если вы делаете постоянно `new MainWindow();` например, то вы создаете постоянно **новое** окно, со своими данными (ввели в одном окне, в другом, например не появится). По правильному, тут надо делать некий сервис, который будет хранить в себе окна и их VM слои (данные), а по запросу либо делать новое, либо вызывать уже имеющееся, но точно не так, как делаете сейчас вы.

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: @aepot, удалось, не посоветуешь что и как учить если только начал учить WPF(XAML)+C# и плюс очень был бы благодарен если бы материалы скинул, книги например

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/373567

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удобнее здесь будет с обобщением

```
public void ShowWindow<T>(Window owner) where T : Window
{
    T newWindow = new T();
    newWindow.Closed += (s, e) => current.Show(); // покажет обратно текущее окно, когда вызванное закроется
    newWindow.Owner = owner; // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.owner#remarks
    owner.Hide();
    newWindow.Show();
}
```

```
ShowWindow<AddServiceWindow>(this);
```